# How do I correctly filter my DataSet by GUID using OData?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, dynamics-crm-2011

**How do I correctly filter my `DataSet` by GUID?**

I'm exposing an OData endpoint, and trying to navigate to the URL:

> `http://localhost:5001/mystuf/api/v2/AccountSet?$filter=AccountId%20eq%20guid%2703a0a47b-e3a2-e311-9402-00155d104c22%27`

When my OData endpoint tries to filter the `DataSet` on that GUID, I am getting:

```
"message": "Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking
an invalid property or method.", "type": "System.NotSupportedException"
> 
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "An error has occurred."
    },
    "innererror": {
      "message": "Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.",
      "type": "System.NotSupportedException",
      "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.ThrowException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.FindValidEntityExpression(Expression exp, String operation)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhereCondition(BinaryExpression be, FilterExpressionWrapper parentFilter, Func`2 getFilter, Boolean negate)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhere(String parameterName, BinaryExpression be, FilterExpressionWrapper parentFilter, Func`2 getFilter, List`1 linkLookups, Boolean negate)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhereBoolean(String parameterName, Expression exp, FilterExpressionWrapper parentFilter, Func`2 getFilter, List`1 linkLookups, BinaryExpression parent, Boolean negate)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhere(QueryExpression qe, String parameterName, Expression exp, List`1 linkLookups)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.GetQueryExpression(Expression expression, Boolean& throwIfSequenceIsEmpty, Boolean& throwIfSequenceNotSingle, Projection& projection, NavigationSource& source, List`1& linkLookups)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute[TElement](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.GetEnumerator[TElement](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.Query`1.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.Query`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__24.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<BufferResponseContentAsync>d__13.MoveNext()"
    }
  }
}
```

The start of the CSDL file looks something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Schema Namespace="Xrm" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm">

      <EntityType Name="Account">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="AccountId" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="TerritoryCode" Type="Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.OptionSetValue" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="LastUsedInCampaign" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="true" />
…
```

The controller that is getting triggered is:

```cs
public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Account> options)
{
    var retval = options.ApplyTo(_accountService.GetAccountSet());

    return Ok(retval);

}
```

And the above `Get()` method applies the filter to:

```cs
public IQueryable<Account> GetAccountSet()
{
    return _xrmServiceContext.AccountSet;
}
```

**How do I correctly filter my `DataSet` by GUID?**

Please note that when I return this instead:

```cs
return _xrmServiceContext.AccountSet.Take(2);
```

Then data is returned correctly to the client (serialization/deserialization correctly works); however, the filter is not applied at all.

Comment: Your OData query is incorrect. The query structure for a filter is as follows: $filter=property eq 'value', not $filter=property eq property 'value'. Try $filter=AccountId eq 'guid value'.

Comment: "The query specified in the URI is not valid. A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Guid' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'."
    },

Comment: /api/v2/AccountSet?$filter=AccountId eq '03a0a47b-e3a2-e311-9402-00155d104c22'

Comment: This means you're trying to compare an Edm.Guid to an Edm.String. I assume your AccountSet field is an Edm.String, so probably if you change it to an Edm.Guid it'll work.

Comment: @ChrisN how would i do that?

Comment: You need to change the backend. I can't do it for you, I'm only familiar with the Olingo framework which is used for exposing OData services in Java, not in c#

Comment: AFAIK, OData will coerse into GUID if you remove the single quotes.

Answer (score 16):

According to [updated documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html) solution depends on type of `AccountId` field.

If `AccountId` type is `Guid` (most probably your case) than comparison with guid literal should be written without `guid` keyword or putting it into quotes. So valid query should look like this:

```
AccountId eq 03a0a47b-e3a2-e311-9402-00155d104c22
```

And result url will be this:

http://localhost:5001/mystuf/api/v2/AccountSet?$filter=AccountId%20eq%2003a0a47b-e3a2-e311-9402-00155d104c22

But if `AccountId` type is `String` and it contains string representation of  guid, you should use rules for string literal and put it in single quotes, like this:

```
AccountId eq '03a0a47b-e3a2-e311-9402-00155d104c22'
```

And result url will be this:

http://localhost:5001/mystuf/api/v2/AccountSet?$filter=AccountId%20eq%20%2703a0a47b-e3a2-e311-9402-00155d104c22%27

You can just test both url to see which one will work for you :)

Comment: `GuidValue` is the name of field from example in documentation about guid literals. Please read next line of my answer with example for current database `AccountId eq 03a0a47b-e3a2-e311-9402-00155d104c22`. I'll remove this example to avoid confusion